# Determine which SQL script file is being used

Tags: sql, command-line, windows-10, sqlplus, oracle12c

I'm starting to learn SQL on class and using SQL command line to start some of the pre-built sql files.

ie
start "directory/file_1.sql"

problem arose during class last week when we were switching to and from multiple different script and I lost track which file I was working on.

at this time, I'm using another prebuilt script that drops all table then start the second script

Is there a way to check which file is currently being used?

//edit
Using sql plus tool for oracle 12c

//edit2
In ongoing confusion of which program I am using, I've attached the screenshot
[image]

//edit3
location of the script file is within windows10

so once I login as scott I do
start "C:\Users\Documents\Oracle SQL\JLDB_Build.sql"
but sometime have to work on 
start "C:\Users\Documents\Oracle SQL\JLDB_Build_5.sql"

then I forget if I'm working on build or build_5

Comment: What DB platform, and what command line tool?  Please tag appropriately

Comment: As far as I can tell, no - not from SQL*Plus. On the other hand, when you **edit** a file, you do that in some editor, don't you? Does it not display file name you're currently working with?

Comment: I know for sure it is oracle 12c... and I was told that the tool is sql plus, but the file that I execute is named "Run SQL Command Line"

Comment: I believe you may be confused.  What you are seeing as 'Run SQL Command Line' is the shortcut that runs SQL Plus.  The scripts you execute after using SQL Plus to log into your Oracle database come after you log into SQL Plus.  The location of your Scripts you are running can be anywhere.  The lack of knowing where your scripts are located on your computer or whatever environment you are working out of is simply something you are going to need to figure out.  My question to you is:  "Where are you storing your script files?.  What folder/directory?".